# Company interested in hiring me, but I want to start in 2 years at the earliest

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, human-resources, germany

Roughly 6 months ago I attended a recruiting event from a company I was not sure I wanted to work for. I really liked the event and the employees that were there but decided that I would rather not try to get a job there. They were interested in me and offered me a shortcut in the recruitment process (I could skip the first part of it).

In the meantime, I changed my mind and am actively considering applying there again. After the event, I received a few emails from them inviting me to some other events I wasn't interested in. Now I am wondering how to best express my interest in the company after not having any contact for several months.

What further complicates my situation is that I am still in my Master's degree, which I will finish in roughly 2 years, so I am not looking for a job right now but in around 2 years time. I'm studying in Germany and the job would be here too. How best to proceed?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to work there or not? If the job is in Germany, can you not study and work at the same time?

Comment: 1 year ago, I was unsure but considering it, 6 months ago I decided against it, now I changed my mind and want to work there. Working while studying is not an option for me, I want to do my internships somewhere else.

Comment: @Gaze Are you trying to get a grad internship or a full-time job upon graduating? Are you asking who to contact because you have been out of touch with them for a while and you don't want a position until after you graduate?

Comment: Full time job after graduation. I suppose my old HR contact is still correct I'm mainly unsure how to phrase it when I first reach out to them again.

Comment: I'm sorry if this comes off rude, but this is the kind of condescending reply that is (rightfully) criticized [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.ctv97094q). Obviously, I won't solve it by aborting all contact. My question is if I need to address the 6 month silence, if I should write them now that I'm interested, even though I know the process very well and should hand in my application in around 18 months. Or keep quiet and reply in 18 months (this is weird I see this myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that you attended a recruiting event and have had no contact with the company since that time.

There's no harm in expressing your interest in the company, and making a general inquiry as to what the process might be to apply there, and what type of positions they are looking to fill.

Typically companies do not have a 2-year hiring window, so you likely wouldn't impact their decision at this point.

Part of being ready for a job when you graduate is to make connections and contacts in the interim, and updating those contacts as the time grows closer.

Comment: Yes, what do I do with these connections? In private, a friendship would require "maintenance", you would write a friend every once in a while to catch up. Is it normal to get to know each other and keep contact details, then just reach out when you need something? (Seems bad) Usually at this company you apply 3-4 months before you start, maximum would be around 6 months I think. Should I just write them that I'm interested but need time to graduate and will notify them in 1.5 years?

Comment: You're right, standard practice is to wait until you're about to graduate and then apply. If you are really interested in this company, then yes, it would probably help to maintain a relationship of some kind, even if infrequent. To write and say you'll get in touch in 18 months might seem a little odd and is perhaps not worth doing. You never know -- your plans might change and you might want a job sooner.